# Scroll a UIScrollView programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, scrollview, coordinates

In my iPhone application, I have a UIScrollview with five pages. Is that possible to tap a button and scroll the pages? for example, I am in the first page and if I press the "Button 5" the fifth page should come over like you scrolling with your hand.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure it is possible!
Check the method `- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated`. When you press the button, call it with the point offset (x and y) and set animated to YES.

Also, if you are using a UIScrollView, it is very recommended by Apple's Human Interface Guidelines that you use a UIPageControl, that is good for two reasons: (1) shows the user in which page he is, and (2) can tell your view controller if it was tapped (however, as the doc says, *"the page control advances only one page in either direction"*, so if you need to jump, let's say, from page 2 to 5, maybe would be better to use buttons).

Comment: You are welcome =)
Don't forget to accept answers if they solved your problem by clicking the checkmark button

Answer (score 3):

you can do this by this one line code.

```
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
```

here you need to provide frame to it that wich part of scrollview you want to show.